# Bitcoin Core - autogen.sh failing on Mac

Tags: bitcoin-core, compiling

I'm working on installing Bitcoin Core for the [mac](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.15.1/doc/build-osx.md). I've cloned the repo and installed the dependencies via brew. I'm trying to run `autogen.sh` but it is failing:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
/usr/local/bin/glibtoolize: line 406: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/glibtoolize: line 2513: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/glibtoolize: line 2513: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/glibtoolize: line 3601: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/glibtoolize: line 3845: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/glibtoolize: line 861: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory
: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
: copying file './ltmain.sh'
/usr/local/bin/glibtoolize: line 3771: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: No such file or directory
configure.ac:45: error: required file 'build-aux/ltmain.sh' not found
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

I'm not sure what is failing. `brew doctor` is clean. `glibtoolize` and `sed` can both be found. There is no `.../Library/ENV` directory, so I'm not sure why that isn't automatically getting created.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Mac 10.12.6
Bitcoin (7b57bc9) - v0.15.1
```

Comment: one observations: normally, capital variables indicate environment/shell vars, so it looks like if a "$" sign is missing, so it is incorrectly interpreted. Also: looking in the forum for "OSX compile" reveals many hits. And lastly: you have installed the command line tools from Xcode, and surely a call to "sed" is ok? (which sed)

Comment: I do have `sed` (`/usr/bin/sed`) and I do have command line tools installed. Any idea where a `$` might be missing? I'll look around at the OSX compile issues. Thanks.

Comment: hmm, just gave it a try, and it works on a clean machine. I followed this instruction:https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md. A "uname -a" returns:
Darwin lulu.local 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Mon Nov 13 21:56:25 PST 2017; root:xnu-3789.72.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 - I have used a non privileged user, and in his home directory did the brew install. Then downloaded bitcoin core (git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin), and then cd to bitcoin and calling ./autogen.sh - no errors ... can you setup a new user, and try the steps in his home dir?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `/usr/local/bin/glibtoolize:` is pointing to the wrong directory

`line  49 : ${SED="/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed"}`

This was changed when homebrew decided to move their paths. See this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440350/sed-directory-not-found-when-running-r-with-e-flag#38471855)

What worked for me was

`brew reinstall libtool`

Answer (score -1):

Easier appraoch:

```
brew install bitcoin
```

However, as Jonas points out, you should be careful with trusting 3rd party package managers. Specifically, you should verify the SHA1 of the package you're getting from Homebrew matches that of the [official release of Bitcoin](https://bitcoincore.org/bin/) from either GitHub or the Bitcoin Core website.

More reading:

[Is Homebrew safe?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/241768)

Example of using GPG to verify a package's signature (in this case the `SHA256SUMS.asc` signature file in https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.15.1/):

[image]

Comment: Using a package manager to install a security critical application is not recommended IMO. What if they deliver a different package, how can the binary be verified by the user?